# Use of undeclared identifier in xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode4.3

So back in xcode 4.2 I had no issues with the following code:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
retval = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");}
```

However when I updated to xcode 4.3.2 I get the error that retval and argc are undeclared identifiers. I know the obvious answer is to declare these two identifiers, but I do not see why I did not have to this back in 4.2.

Any help is appreciated,
Ashan

Comment: does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

i think it may be because you have automatic reference counting on